# How to use non-browser forms created by Infopath Filler (published to a Sharepoint Form Library)?

Tags: 2010, development, infopath, custom-form, office-integration

I have requirements to create Infopath Filler 2010 forms. They are non-browser and are not served through Sharepoint Infopath Services (so require Infopath installed on all clients) but have supposedly richer client capabilities and are supposedly easier to develop (really only to design) while all clients in organisation have Infopath installed locally.

So, I create Filler form by:
in Infopath Designer 2010 I chose "File" --> "New" -->  "Blank Form (Infopath Filler)"

[image: Infopath 2010: Available Form Templates]

Fig.1. Infopath 2010: Available Form Templates

and publish it by File --> Publish --> btn "Sharepoint Server"

- the latter has description:
  **Publish form to a Sharepoint Library**

  - Create or update a form library form on Sharepoint
  - Users can access this form online (my question: How?)

to _http://sptest:666/InfoPathFormLib/

[image: Publishing "Sharepoint Server"]

Fig.2.1. Publishing "Sharepoint Server"

[image: Publishing browser-disabled (Infopath Filler created) form by pressing "Sharepoint Server" button]

Fig.2.2. Publishing browser-disabled (Infopath Filler created) form by pressing "Sharepoint Server" button

[image: When I click "Add document" green-cross image-button]

Fig.3. Upon clicking "Add document" green-cross image-button

[image: gives an error in Firefox Mozill "The form cannot be modified in a Web browser. To open the form, use Microsoft InfoPath"]

Fig.4.1. ... gives an error in Firefox Mozill "The form cannot be modified in a Web browser. To open the form, use Microsoft InfoPath."

[image: ...though opens itself in InfoPath Filler from Internet Explorer]

Fig.4.2. ...though opens itself in InfoPath Filler from Internet Explorer

and modifying the opened in Infopath Filler 2010 form

I have only the following options to "save" (and/or export) it:

- File --> Save As (Formxxx.xml)
- File -->  "Save and Send" --> Send Using E-mail

  - E-mail message body contains a copy of this form
  - Allows recipients fill out this form in Outlook
  - Recipients must have matching versions of Infopath and Outlook
- Export to Web

  - Save this form in a format that can be opened in any Web browser
  - Export this form as a Single File Web Page (.mht, .mhtml)

[image]

Fig.5.

<s>I believe that I have the same (versions of) Outlook 2010 and Infopath 2010  since I am sending and opening E-mail on the same machine.</s>

But I cannot modify the fields of form received by E-mail --> See **Updated** below

Though I cannot find how any modifications go back to Sharepoint lists on the nasis  , how this off-line (from Sharepoint) Email  (or saved .mht Web Page or .xml data) form is supposed to be used?

What are the possible ways of using Infopath Filler non-browser-enabled (off-line from Sharepoint) forms?

What are the sense and possible ways of specifically publishing non-browser forms templates to a Sharepoint Forms Library?

**Updated:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Fig.6. he InfoPath Filler created forms are opened as in Fig.4 and the data modified in it upon :Security and Trust" configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the question, if it was blurred, was how to have modifications in/from (non-browser-enabled or browser-disabled) Infopath Filler forms end up into their external  datasources (Sharepoint lists, MS SQL Server database tables or webservices).

Te problem is that in Infopath Filler only data in the main data source are synchronized with external data sources while the external data sources are alwats put into Infopath Filler only to secondary data sources.

And the solution to it is not OOTB, straightforward, easy, documented, on the surface or even free (of charge).
Cf. :

- [Clayton's SharePoint Madness. InfoPath – Copy SharePoint List Data to Main Data Source](http://claytoncobb.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/infopath-copy-sharepoint-list-data-to-main-data-source/)
- [InfoPath doesn't allow promoting fields from secondary data sources in a web form?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/sharepoint2010customization/thread/05dbb093-3ca6-4b1c-ba26-ae94a052014d)
- [Differences between Main Vs.Secondary Data Sources in Infopath](http://pravahaminfo.blogspot.com/2011/05/differences-between-main-vssecondary.html)
- [Qdabra InfoPath Accelerator (qRules). 30-daysFree Trial](http://www.qdabra.com/en/products/qRules_overview.aspx)

BTW, there are a lot of (if not all) blogs, tutorials, videos on-line or paper books on Infopath that "illustrate" and teach  the use of Infopath Filler's Master/Detail control without even mentioning this unavoidable necessity to cope data to main data source (from secondary ones). And by this essentially dumping the time, trust and enthusiasm of their readers.

Answer (score 0):

Your form library needs to be configured to open forms in InfoPath.

- Navigate to **Form Library settings** > **Advanced Settings**
- Choose **Open in the client application** for **Opening Documents in the Browser** option

You also need to [define a Submit connection for your form](http://www.edutechnow.com/?p=493).

More details on how to [Configure the default open behavior for browser-enabled documents](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837425.aspx).